# URL opening in all browsers even when user not logged in?

Tags: php

My url is opening in all browsers even when I am using sessions. Ex abc.com/123.php without users logged in. This opens up in all browsers. I am using this code.**All codes are in < php open/close tags** ok codes which ia m using are

```
         <?php
       session_start();

         if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'])) {
     if (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] > 600) {
    // session timed out, last request is longer than 10 minutes ago
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header("location:userlogin.php");
}
  } else {
$_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] = time();
   }

        if($_SESSION['username']=="");
        ?>
```

Comment: the else block is not within the code. The php tag ?> should be after the else block?

Comment: yes its that way only

Comment: Try freelancer.com or something similar and pay someone to do this for you. You're posting this daily without any progress.

Comment: @Onimusha get something from deximat you will learn more.Add below codes for your knowledge as you failed to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this compiles well. Because there are a couple of problems.

Be careful with this line of code:

```
if($_SESSION['username']=="");
```

This means that `true` part of this `if` statement finishes at semicolon.

Second thing is that your `else` part is never executed but printed as regular HTML.

I would write it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'])) {
  if (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] > 600) {
    // session timed out, last request is longer than 10 minutes ago
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header("location:userlogin.php");
  }
} else {
  $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] = time();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
?>
 ///////SOME HTML CODE/////

<?php
} else {
  header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
}
?>
```

And I believe that is what you intended to to with closing `<?php` tag.

Also for readability I suggest you to do just this:

```
if ($_SESSION['username']!="") {
  header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
}
```

So you don't even need else part, because as soon as header is set, he will be redirected.

Comment: hi url still opening without logging  in new browswers after clearing all caches

Comment: is your condition ok? $_SESSION['username']=="" does this mean that user is logged in?

Comment: No, I am saying this should somehow check if user is logged in or not, since I don't see code for logging in, I can't say if this is correct or not. When you login user you must be setting this with something. If it is empty string that this could be ok.

Comment: and if he is not logged in? It is not set? Maybe apropriate check would be if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) ?

Comment: No still logging in with  url

Comment: He's posting this daily with no progress. I recommend not wasting your time. Sorry questioner but you need to hire a professional to do this

Comment: Ok, I will edit this post try to use that code, when you check if $_SESSION['username'] is null (not set) and you try to compare it with == with "" it will try to get their common type and "" and null are empty value, so null == "" will return true. You can use === or you can check if variable is set like I mentioned in comment before. === except checking values it checks if two parameters are of same type.

Comment: @Onimusha if u dont know answers please let others find a solution.Yours didnt worked at all.

Comment: @Deximat It worked like a charm.Bingo on target.People like you really rock.Its working perfect

Answer (score 0):

Because your

```
else {
header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
   }
```

is outside of `<?php ?>`

**Try This:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'])) {
if (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] > 600) {
    // session timed out, last request is longer than 10 minutes ago
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header("location:userlogin.php");
}
else {
$_SESSION['LAST_REQUEST_TIME'] = time();
 }

 if($_SESSION['username']=="");

 ///////your code/////

}
else {
header("location:to_some_login_page.php");
   }
?>
```